# How to get the number in front of a searchstring with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can i filter the number in front of a searched word e.g. the searchstring is *minutes* the string:

> hey joe, there are 5 fishes in 45 minutes you can eat

should give the result: *45*.

What's the best way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. All you need is the right RegEx like the one below:

```
(\d*) minutes
```

A simple code that works is:

```js
var str = "hey joe, there are 5 fishes in 45 minutes you can eat";
var regex = /(\d*) minutes/g;
var found = str.match(regex);
console.log(found);
```

To get the value in the capture group, which is what you need, use `RegEx.exec()`:

```js
var str = "hey joe, there are 5 fishes in 45 minutes you can eat";
var regex = /(\d*) minutes/g;
var found = regex.exec(str);
console.log(found[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you, my first solution seems similar: str.match(/(\d+) Minuten/)[0]; and str = parseInt(str);